# I can't get rid of linux (can't boot usb)

Tags: boot, usb, windows, usb-installation

On my laptop Ubuntu 18 is installed. But I want windows 10 back. So I created win10 bootable usb stick on another computer using rufus. But I couldn't boot it when computer starts. I select usb on boot selection, but still purple screen appears. And then ubuntu starts like normally. I dont know what to do now. Please help me, how can i get to windows 10 installing screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved the problem. I changed "partition scheme" from GPT to MBR in Rufus, when creating bootable usb. Now it boots to Windows installation.